# LUIS duration in hours using built-in dateTime entity

Tags: datetime, botframework, bots, duration, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to build a bot in C# using Microsoft Bot Framework and LUIS. This bot must be able to book a room for a certain duration.
Currently it works well with the prebuilt datetime of LUIS for durations in minutes, but it takes hours as a time and not as a duration.

Example:

`Book the room for 20 minutes` works fine, it books the room now for the 20 next minutes.

`Book the room for 1 hour` is understood as `book the room at 1PM`. So the reply I get is `for how long ?`.

*Edit*

How can i have luis detect hours as duration if followed by specified words within LUIS

P.S: I use french culture in LUIS

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What have you looked at so far? (Example URLs?) What code have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, thank you

Currently we have simply tried to add the duration understanding to our bot, and figured it did not work proprelyo in luis itself (the timex entity returned is not correct).

So the question here (was not clear sorry about that) is : Is there a propoer way to do this within LUIS ?

Comment: Entities cannot be resolved based on the associated words in LUIS. But its weird that '1 hour' is identified as '1 pm'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem by creating a list entity of the words used for duration in fresh ("pendant", "durant",...).

We then created a composite entity and added datetimeV2 and our list entity as childs.

When we receive the composit entity from LUIS, we know we have to take the hour of the datetime as a duration.

It works really nice now.